# Split a comma delimited Pandas Column of Type Object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df with a column that have a mix of values like so

```
| ID       | home_page                                       |
| ---------| ------------------------------------------------|
| 1        | facebook.com, facebook.com, meta.com            |
| 2        | amazon.com                                      |
| 3        | twitter.com, dev.twitter.com, twitter.com       |
```

I want to create a new column that contain the unique values from home_page column. The final output should be

```
| ID       | home_page                                       | unique                    |
| -------- | --------------                                  |---------------------------|
| 1        | facebook.com, facebook.com, meta.com            | facebook.com,meta.com     |
| 2        | amazon.com                                      | amazon.com                |
| 3        | twitter.com, dev.twitter.com, twitter.com       |twitter.com,dev.twitter.com|
```

I tried the following:

```
final["home_page"] = final["home_page"].str.split(',').apply(lambda x : ','.join(set(x)))
```

But when I do that I get

```
TypeError: float object is not iterable
```

The column has no NaN but just in case I tried

```
final["home_page"] = final["home_page"].str.split(',').apply(lambda x : ','.join(set(x)))
```

But the entire column return empty when doing that

Comment: How are your two attempts different? They look the same. Also, are you sure you don't have NaN's? How did you check? Does this work? `final["home_page"].fillna('').str.split(',').apply(lambda x : ','.join(set(x)))`

Comment: @Steven still getting TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that this is coming from `np.nan` values which are of type float. The issue happens here: `set(np.nan)`. The following should work for you (and should be faster).

```
df["home_page"].str.replace(' ', '').str.split(',').apply(np.unique)
```

If you actually want a string at the end you can throw the following at the end:

```
.apply(lambda x: ','.join(str(i) for i in x))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: That is probably because you overwrote `home_page` column with my first example and it is now of type `np.array`. Try creating a new column, that is safer in general!

Comment: Not sure what it was but I did this and it worked df["home_page"].apply(np.unique).apply(lambda x: ','.join(str(i) for i in x))

Comment: I am 99% sure this is happening because you are making multiple calls on the same column after changing it, probably is a tool like Jupyter. You are overwriting the column, and now it is type np.array rather than str. Then the second time you run it it doesn't work. You should do `final["home_page_unique"] = final["home_page"].` to fix it.